# k-polynomial time approximation algorithm for set cover (k = max size of subsets)

Tags: optimization, algorithms, linear-programming

Given a universe set $U = \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ and a collection of $m$ subsets $S_1, S_2, \dots S_m \subseteq U$, find the minimum collection of subsets that cover $U$.

I am specifically trying to find a factor $k$ polynomial time approximation algorithm for set cover where $k$ is the largest size of the subsets. In other words, $k = \max_{i=1}^m|S_i|$.

I have written the Integer Linear Program as follows:\

where $x_i =1 $ when the subset $S_i$ is selected, $0$ otherwise
\begin{array}{lll}
\min: \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\\
\text{s.t.} \sum_{i: v\in S_i} x_i \geq 1 \ \forall v \in U\\
\ x_i \leq 1\\
\ x_i \in \mathbb{N}
\end{array}

And I also have the linear programming relaxation as follows:
\begin{array}{lll}
\min: \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\\
\text{s.t.} \sum_{i: v\in S_i} x_i \geq 1 \ \forall v \in U\\
\ x_i \leq 1\\
\ x_i \geq 0\\
\end{array}

So, I was thinking to construct a set $A = \{i : x_i \geq 1/k \}$, then by construction $|A| \leq k\sum_i x_i \leq k OPT $, where $OPT$ represents the optimal solution of the integer linear programing.

But I am not sure how to proceed afterwards to prove the set $A$ is indeed a set cover .  Any help/hints/correction would be appreciated.

Comment: You can omit the $x_i\le 1$ in both formulations. You have shown the factor of $k$ for the objective value. Now you need to show that your candidate $A$ is a set cover. That is, you need to show that taking $x_i=1$ for $i\in A$ is an integer feasible solution.

Comment: can you explain more about how to show set $A$ is a set cover, that's the part I'm stuck for so long.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $\sum_{j\in B} y_j\ge 1$, then $y_j\ge 1/|B|$ for at least one $j$.  (It is easy to prove the contrapositive.)

Now use this fact to show that the integer linear programming constraints are satisfied when you take $x_i=1$ for $i\in A$.

Comment: I understand about your hint and I tried to work around it, but I still got stuck at some point. Would you mind explicitly let me know how to show the integer linear programing constraint are satisfied?

Comment: See https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~yaron/AM221-S16/lecture_notes/AM221_lecture21.pdf and https://ugtcs.berkeley.edu/src/approx-sp19/scribe-notes-1.pdf